# Cocoa app on old OSX 10.5.6 - configuration for maximum compatibility

Tags: c++, cocoa, osx-snow-leopard

I am very new to C ++ programming for OSX.

What is the configuration that I need to set in Xcode on the old OSX 10.5.6 to create a simple Cocoa application but that also works on new operating systems.

What compiler do I need to set, the architecture etc ???

I hope the questions are not very silly...

Answer (score -1):

To run on the latest versions of macOS, you must build a 64-bit app. In the Architectures build setting, make sure 64-bit Intel (x86_64) is one of the architectures you're building for.